# Refactoring of the if statement

Tags: c#

How to make this code better? I need to increase the value that I add to **FoodLevel**, on **3** with each new **PlayersLevel**

```
if (PlayersLevel == 0)
{
    button1.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + 0].ToString();
    button3.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + 1].ToString();
    button4.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + 2].ToString();
}
else if (PlayersLevel == 1)
{
    button1.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + 3].ToString();
    button3.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + 4].ToString();
    button4.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + 5].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
button1.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + PlayersLevel * 3].ToString();
button3.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + PlayersLevel * 3 + 1].ToString();
button4.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + PlayersLevel * 3 + 2].ToString();
```

Comment: The use case seems odd, so I wonder if there is an even better solution (in terms of design). This is definitely the right answer for the posted question though.

Comment: should that be `button1.Text = textForFoodButtons[FoodLevel + (PlayersLevel * 3)].ToString();` and so forth for each button.

Comment: @Robbert Yes, absolutely! fixed.